# Create new column for data after each iteration of a for loop in python

Tags: python, numpy

Using the next code I want to put the results in columns for differents values of m

```
import numpy as np 
for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
   for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1):
       coef = 2*m/n
       print coef
```

The results of this is:

```
0
0
0
2
1
0
4
2
1
6
3
2
```

I want to get this

```
0 0 0
2 1 0
4 2 1
6 3 2
```

or get directly the column, which is the sum of values of the rows

```
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
2 + 1 + 0 = 3
4 + 2 + 1 = 7
6 + 3 + 2 = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma after the print so we don't add a newline  and another print outside the inner loop to separate each line:

```
import numpy as np
for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
   for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1):
       coef = 2*m/n
       print coef,
   print
```

Which will give you:

```
0 0 0
2 1 0
4 2 1
6 3 2
```

Or using print as a function:

```
from __future__ import print_function


import numpy as np

for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
    print(*(2 * m / n for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1)))
```

To get the sum, we can just use the builtin *sum* function using a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) in the inner loop:

```
import numpy as np

for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
    print(sum(2 * m / n for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1)))
```

Which will give you:

```
0
3
7
11
```

For completeness, the equivalent print_function code to  the first example would be setting `end=" "`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
   for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1):
       coef = 2*m/n
       print(coef, end=" ")
   print()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood correctly, you want to create new array where its columns are like you've specified.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.zeros([3,4])
for m in np.arange(0, 4, 1):
    col = []
    for n in np.arange(1, 4, 1):
        coef = int(2*m/n)
        col.append(coef)
    a[:, int(m)] = col

print(a.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with a loop would work just as well with `range`.  No need to use `numpy`.

But if this is an exercise in learning `numpy`, I'd suggest a different approach.

Make an array directly from the ranges.  `//` is integer division.

```
In [99]: A=2*np.arange(4)[:,None]//np.arange(1,4)

In [100]: A
Out[100]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [4, 2, 1],
       [6, 3, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

You can sum across columns with an array method:

```
In [101]: A.sum(axis=1)
Out[101]: array([ 0,  3,  7, 11], dtype=int32)
```

To get a nice format, without brackets and such, create a row formatting string:

```
In [102]: fmt = '%d + %d + %d = %d'               

In [103]: for row in A:                           
    print(fmt%(tuple(row)+(row.sum(),))) 
   .....:     
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
2 + 1 + 0 = 3
4 + 2 + 1 = 7
6 + 3 + 2 = 11
```

(The function form of print is normal in Python3, and available in 2.7)

I could have used a variation on this to write this to a file via `np.savetxt`.

```
In [104]: A.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)  # sum in column array shape
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0],
       [ 3],
       [ 7],
       [11]], dtype=int32)

In [105]: A1 = np.concatenate((A, A.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)),axis=1)

In [106]: A1     # the values and sum in one array
Out[106]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  1,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  2,  1,  7],
       [ 6,  3,  2, 11]], dtype=int32)

In [107]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A1,fmt=fmt)

In [108]: cat test.txt    # look at the resulting file
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
2 + 1 + 0 = 3
4 + 2 + 1 = 7
6 + 3 + 2 = 11
```

A Python2.7 version without numpy:

```
>>> for m in range(4):
...     row = [2*m/n for n in range(1,4)]
...     fmt = '%d + %d + %d = %d'
...     print fmt%(tuple(row)+(sum(row),))
... 
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
2 + 1 + 0 = 3
4 + 2 + 1 = 7
6 + 3 + 2 = 11
```